# Accessing an array from another class

Tags: ios, ipad

I have an array called client in one of my classes and I want to use the information in that array in another class that i have. I have set up the property and synthesized the array in my first class. The code for my first class is

```
@synthesize client;

...


- (IBAction)testing:(id)sender {
    NSString *textContent = myTextView.text;
    textContent = [textContent stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    client = [textContent componentsSeparatedByString:@"."]; 
    NSLog(@"%@", client);
}
```

In my second class I tried importing the h file for my first class and then just accessing the array. The code that I am using is

```
- (IBAction)ButtonStuff:(id)sender {
    ArrayManipulationViewController *myClass = [[ArrayManipulationViewController alloc]init];
    NSLog(@"Second Interface");
    NSArray *test = myClass.client;
    NSLog(@"%@", test);
}
```

Comment: It's hard to be sure from what you've written but consider that `alloc` creates a new object...that is, a completely different one from what you had before and which doesn't know anything about what you stored in the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

To access object from multiple classes, a common approach is to declare the object in the parent class, and then pass a shared instance of that object to all child classes that require access. For instance, you could declare the array in the AppDelegate, and set array properties in your subclasses, and pass the instance of the array from the AppDelegate to all your subclasses.

Eg: create an NSArray (myArray) in your app delegate, then in the AppDelegate implantation, pass the myArray instance to your sub view controllers using properties.

Or, if you'd prefer; you can declare the array in your first class, and then pass the array instance from your first class to your second class using properties. Then, any changes made in your second class will be available in your first class, since the INSTANCE is the same.

UPDATED ANSWER:
For the second approach, you're best declaring the array in your first class implementation, and then when you instantiate the second class, pass the instance of the array to the second class using properties. In this example, you'll need to have an NSArray property in your second class to be able to pass the array over to it using `[secondClassInstance setClient: client];`

Your second class interface might look like this:

```
@interface SecondClass : NSObject
{
   NSArray *client;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *client; // don't forget to synthesize
@end
```

Then, in your first class, you can do the following to pass over your instance of the array:

```
NSArray *client = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Object 1", @"Object 2"];

//...

SecondClass *secondClass = [[SecondClass alloc] init];
[secondClass setClient: client]; // passing the original client instance here

// don't forget to release secondClass instance when finished
```

Comment: For what I am trying to do the second method you talked about where the array will be the same is what I want. I was trying to use properties but I am still new to Objective c and xcode so I do not think I did right. Could you elaborate a little bit about how to do it?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Hopefully this will be of more use to you, Dravus.

Comment: Ok I tried all of this and when I do an NSLog of the array in the second class it says null. However when I do an NSLog in the first class it does print out the array correctly. I am not sure what I am doing incorrectly if you need anything from my code please let me know.

Comment: Are you sure that the NSLog is executing AFTER the array has been passed over? Make sure you don't do the NSLog in your init method. If it still doesn't work, I'll post the exact code for all files.

Comment: I am sure the array has been passed over first. The way that I have it set up is that there are two interfaces that I made, both with a button. When I press the button on the first interface it creates the array prints it out, passes it over and goes to the next screen. When I press the second button all it does is try to print out the array again but I just get Null

Comment: Hello, I have the same problem with accessing an array from a different view. I have `initWithObjects:[self firstViewArray];` my `NSMutable *array`, then I `setSecondViewArray:array` but my secondViewArray will still be `(null)`. What could be wrong?